# Are there any performance details available for the D8 Double Bubble engines?

Tags: jet-engine, efficiency, double-bubble-d8

For the [D8 Double Bubble](http://www.aurora.aero/d8/), what are the thrust requirements for the engines? Has it been stated what the estimated max thrust will be for each engine?

[image]
Source: [sputniknews.com](https://sputniknews.com/us/201609171045397924-nasa-develops-new-jet/)

Comment: All details in: [NASA N+3 MIT Team Final Review](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/N+3/Final_slides.pdf). for the D8.5: 3 geared turbofans, boundary layer ingestion, bypass ratio of 20 and 37.7 kN.

Comment: @mins 37.7 kN sounds like the answer... ;)